# Attach event listeners to in application items with Adobe extendscript

Tags: event-handling, adobe-illustrator, extendscript

The title pretty much sums it up.  But, basically is it possible with Adobe applications to add event listeners to in-application items, such as a pathItem in Illustrator?

So I want something to happen when I click on a pathItem in Illustrator - or something like that.  Is this possible?

I'm afraid I know the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry. That is not possible with scripting. Maybe with a plugin.

Comment: Earning achievement points just for saying no does not feel good at all. :-(

Comment: Lol - it kind of confirmed my suspicion

Answer (score 1):

You can use  [Scriptographer](https://scriptographer.org/about/), it's a scripting plugin for Illustrator with own scripting engine with keyboard and mouse events.

But this plugin works with old illustrator's version (CS5 and older).

Comment: I do at times, but it's buggy as hell.  Causes weird problems that require restart.

Answer (score 1):

wouldn't this work to handle the click/selection event?

```
    AIEventAdapter.getInstance().addEventListener(AIEvent.ART_SELECTION_CHANGED,function(event) {});
```

Comment: Seems like a good idea.  I can't try it now, but it's creative.  I'll try it later and let you know.  THanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about exported PDF's or SVG's, you are able to add a link in the attributes panel and insert any javascript you like:

javascript:alert('you clicked on this line');

If you want something to happen in Illustrator, while you are using the program, then there is no way as far as I know to affect anything.

You can run scripts using keyboard shortcuts.

If you could clarify your use case I might be able to help more.